# azure invited user with external identity password reset/change

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I have an application where currently all the users are in azure AD tenant of our subscription. So in application to change their password we are dealing with graph api. Now have to change this so that the uses will not be maintain in our tenant but we will be adding federation for google and facebook external identity so that users will be using ther respective account credentials.I know we cant control this from the app.Now my question is how to manage this password change/reset in our app? how to design this?

Thanks,
mbr

Comment: You'd probably have to redirect them to their login provider's reset page.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Just like @juunas said, you need to redirect them to their login providers' reset page. For example, if the user who is using facebook account clicks 'Forgot Password' button, just redirect the user to `https://www.facebook.com/login/identify/?ctx=recover&ars=royal_blue_bar`